# Getting error for all the keywords in robot framework - Unknown Keyword error after restarting my machine

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am getting error for all keywords now and not getting suggestions as well, I am not sure what did I change recently as it was working fine.
Input Text, Click Button are not showing any issues.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the test from the command line? Is this an error in your robot installation or just an error in your editor?

Comment: Its running fine, its just an error in the editor

Comment: Well, being an editor issue, it wouldn't hurt if you say which one is it, and what plugins you're using. Also, drop the selenium tag - it doesn't have anything to do with the problem; and add any IDE error logs, if there are such.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing Selenium Library, reload project and retry.